# Basic importing coordinates into R and setting projection

Tags: geospatial, spatial

Ok, I am trying to upload a .csv file, get it into a spatial points data frame and set the projection system to WGS 84. I then want to determine the distance between each point This is what I have come up with but I

```
cluster<-read.csv(file = "cluster.csv", stringsAsFactors=FALSE)
coordinates(cluster)<- ~Latitude+Longitude  
cluster<-CRS("+proj=longlat +datum=WGS84") 
d<-dist2Line(cluster)
```

This returns an error that says

```
Error in .pointsToMatrix(p) : 
  points should be vectors of length 2, matrices with 2 columns, or inheriting from a SpatialPoints* object
```

But this isn't working and I will be honest that I don't fully comprehend importing and manipulating spatial data in R. Any help would be great. Thanks

Comment: If you're still having problems, can you dput() a few rows of your data and I'll have a look for you.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to determine the issue I was running into. With WGS 84, the longitude comes before the latitude. This is just backwards from how all the GPS data I download is formatted (e.g. lat-long). Hope this helps anyone else who runs into this issue!

thus the code should have been

```
cluster<-read.csv(file = "cluster.csv", stringsAsFactors=FALSE)
coordinates(cluster)<- ~Longitude+Latitude  
cluster<-CRS("+proj=longlat +datum=WGS84")
```